# How do you display icons for various file types in an iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, file-icons

I'd like to know if anyone has found a way to display icons for different file types such as MS Word documents, Adobe Flash documents etc. on iPhone using iOS SDK?

It has an equivalent way on MacOS : using the method `iconForFileType` of the class `NSWorkspace`.

Comment: If you want to have your own application's icon be associated with a file type, system wide, you can do what I describe in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2781290/19679 Are you asking how to create custom icons for various file types viewed within your own application (though UIDocumentInteractionController or the like)?

Comment: In fact I want to create a file explorer and so I want to display the icons of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `UIDocumentInteractionController`:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSArray *icons
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. In addition, in iOS 6.1, we have to provide an NSURL (which does NOT need to exist) to the UIDocumentInteractionController.